# Trying to append test results to a text file in order under the correct headings

Tags: python, list, testing, text

> Trying to get these series of tests to add their results to content and then at the end of the script to write the collected content to a text file under the correct headings dictated under criteria. The first test works properly but none of the ones after that. No error, just no appended information. I need to figure out what I'm doing wrong and how to have the content be appended under the right sections. Please help!

```
def writeReport(): #writes content to report file without truncating
   reportFile = 'report.txt'
   bigspacer = '================================================================================================================================'
   littlespacer = '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
   si = ' Single Install'
   criteria = ['0',
      '1 Did the installation complete successfully',
      '2 Installed shortcuts. *.ico files should get installed in bin folder to be used by registry entries and IQR/IQJ images %CADIQ_HOME%\\samples\\cadiq\\compare_*\\*.iqr',
      '3 Installed files/folders match those of the central area',
      '4 Was the license file correctly copied and updated (temp lic when only the viewer is installed (lic panel should not be displayed))',
      '5 Were correct CIQEL files in correct location (updated correctly)',
      '6 Were the correct cadscript/bin/plat-XXX/cadscript_XXX installed (no extras)',
      '7 Was cadiq or cadiq.bat updated correctly',
      '8 Were the correct version_xx.txt and cadscript.cfg files in their correct place',
      '9 Was cadscript.cfg updated correctly',
      '10 Was the correct pdelib files there',
      '11 Does a CADIQ Analysis work',
      '12 Overall Pass/Fail']
   installpath = drive + ':\\CADIQ\\v' + version + '_' + cadsys + '_si'
   passes = 0
   fails = 0
   NAs = 0

   content = bigspacer + '\n' + cadsys + si + '\n' + bigspacer + '\n'

# loop for each test criteria
   for test in criteria:
      if test == criteria[0]:
         continue

      content += '\n' + littlespacer + '\n' + test + '\n'
      testsuccess = 1
      nonapplicable = 0
      relevantfolder = None
  

# test 1
      if test == criteria[1]:         
         content += 'Things' + '\n'

     
# test 2 (Icons are on desktop, try looking here in test)
      if test == criteria[2]:
     content += 'Things' + '\n'     

# test 3
      if test == criteria[3]:
         content += 'Things' + '\n'

# test 4
      if test == criteria[4]:
         content += 'Things' + '\n'

# test 5
      if test == criteria[5]:
         content += 'Things' + '\n'

# test 6
      if test == criteria[6]:
         content += 'Things' + '\n'

# test 7
      if test == criteria[7]:
         content += 'Things' + '\n'

# test 8
      if test == criteria[8]:
         content += 'Things' + '\n'

# test 9
      if test == criteria[9]:
         content += 'Things' + '\n'

# test 10
      if test == criteria[10]:
         content += 'Things' + '\n'

# test 11
      if test == criteria[11]:
         content += 'Things' + '\n'

# test 12
      if test == criteria[12]:
         content += 'Things' + '\n'
# end loop

# write
   with open(reportFile, 'a') as f:
      f.write(content)
```

Comment: My wild guess is that `content` is being constructed but `reportFile` is being written somewhere you're not expecting. If you `print(content)` at the end instead of writing to a file, what happens? Edit: Ah, no, you said the first test is working properly.

Comment: Hmm, so I did print it and the information is there in the correct place. It's just not writing it to the file for some reason. So it is being collected by content correctly just not written correctly. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

it's because every time you write something to a .txt file with python the entire file gets wiped and then it writes what you input, so when you run it the first time the file gets written the second, third, fourth... time the file's content gets cancelled and re-written because of this you don't see any change, so you should try something like this:

```
with open(reportFile, "r") as file:
    old = file.read()
#then 
with open(reportFile, 'a') as f:
    f.write(old + "\n" + content)
```

i'm sure there's a better way for doing that but this work too

Comment: Giving it a whirl. I will let you know what happens.

Comment: Are File and reportFile supposed to be different? Are they referencing the same file? That part confuses me.

Comment: For some reason that created an infinite loop. Also for some reason I think I got it working now.